# Passing Javascript Variable Into Template Toolkit Without Form

Tags: jquery, catalyst, template-toolkit

I would like a second  menu to be updated dynamically based on the current selection of a first  menu, without the user submitting a form.

I am learning to use Catalyst Framework with Template Toolkit, and the data for these  menus is stored in a Model that I access using the TT directives.

I have previously used JQuery's .change() method to retrieve the status of a  menu, and pass it to CGI for processing.

Can I do something similar with Template Toolkit?  How do I pass a javascript variable into the TT directive?  Other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, but it's critical to bear in mind that once the template is rendered as HTML, TT plays no further part. It sounds like your previous experience with CGI will get you most of the way there: your `.change()` event will have to fire a Catalyst action that returns some JSON content for your menu.

Whatever variables need to be set up-front can be handled via TT, e.g. *untested*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu1').change(function(){
        var menuopt = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "[% c.uri_for('/my/action') %]",
            data: "menu1=" + menuopt,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                $.map(data, function(item) {
                    // create menu2 here
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think it is .change(), not .onchange()

Comment: Also, it's $(this).val();    Otherwise, Thank you! This is very helpful.

Comment: I did say it was untested :-). I'll correct the answer to match the question. Glad to help.

Comment: FYI, the recommended way to attach events in jQuery is with `on`: `$('#menu1').on( 'change', function() { ... }` http://api.jquery.com/on/